# Sign Up / Log In page header looks funny

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, login

The page header for the Sign Up / Log In page looks a little funny:

[image]

The white Background on the header doesn't match the text. Also it may be debatable whether it's intended to break the background theme there. Personally I think it would be better to keep the background theme intact and just highlight the header bar. (Maybe transparent background for extra fancy:))

Comment: I don't have any details on when or how this was fixed, but I don't currently see this behavior any longer as we don't show the banner on the sign-up page.